# How to apply rule to classes when they are children of either of two parent classes?

Tags: css

I have parents `.category-view` and `.search-results`.

Each of those can have child `.special-price` that I want to style.

But I do not want to style `.product-view .special-price`.

Must I spell out multiple paths like this:

```
.category-view .special-price, .search-results .special-price {

}
```

Or is there a shorter way, something like

```
.category-view/.search-results .special-price {

}
```

Furthermore, I actually want to style both .special-price and .old-price, so is there some way to do that? Like

```
.category-view/.search-results .special-price/.old-price {

}
```

... that would affect both of those children when they are below either of those parents?

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime use-case for using a CSS pre-processor like SASS/SCSS. In SCSS, you could specify the following nested rule:

```
.category-view, 
.search-results {

    .special-price,
    .old-price {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The nested rule helps avoid repetition while authoring your stylesheets. The final output in CSS would give you the desired rules:

```
.category-view .special-price, 
.category-view .old-price, 
.search-results .special-price,
.search-results .old-price {
        /* profit */
}
```

The main purpose of CSS pre-processors is to help you author your stylesheets more efficiently, which is the root of your question. I would strongly consider looking in to SASS/SCSS for your needs. See here: http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if CSS had the capability built in. I will look into this, as it would probably make my 2400-line CSS file more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `:not` css selector:

```
.special-price:not(.product-view)
{
}
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2bjJ/

Answer (score 0):

This is the most reliable form:

```
.category-view .special-price,
.search-results .special-price,
.category-view .old-price,
.search-results .old-price {
/*STYLE*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
.category-view .special-price, .search-results .special-price {

}
```

there is no shorter way than chaining your selectors seperated by a ','